# How to stop cursor flickering over mapbox marker icons?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

How do I stop cursor flickering over my Mapbox icons?  Here is the live site where you can see the problem when hovering over the marker icons:  https://rustic-waters-group.thesparksite.com/lakes/

Here is my code:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZG1pdHJpbWFydGluIiwiYSI6ImNreHRobHRmcjVqM3cydmt5NWkxdWNibTcifQ.CuN5Dwc963TW-BKRcowxBA';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/dmitrimartin/ckxtj5aur4fvv15mrhmihala8',
  center: [-89.2, 44.33],
  zoom: 9.2
});

map.on('load', () => {

  const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeButton: false,
    closeOnClick: false
  });

  map.on('mouseenter', 'lakes', (event) => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(event.point, {
      layers: ['lakes']
    });
    if (event.features.length === 0) return;
    popup.setLngLat(features[0].geometry.coordinates);
    popup.setHTML('<h3 class="lake-popup">' + features[0].properties.title + '</h3>');
    popup.setMaxWidth("calc(100vw - 40px);");
    popup.addTo(map);
  });

  map.on('mouseleave', 'lakes', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    popup.remove();
  });

  map.on('click', 'lakes', (event) => {
    const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(event.point, {
      layers: ['lakes']
    });
    if (event.features.length === 0) return;
    window.location.href = ('/lakes/' + features[0].properties.url + '/');
  });

  document.getElementById("lakes-header").onmouseover = function() {
    MyMouseOver();
  };

  function MyMouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("lakes-header").style.display = "none";
  }

});
```

Comment: I don't see any flickering. What do you mean, more precisely? I do notice something a bit weird, in that the hit box for each icon seems to be quite a few pixels below it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from the popup box on top of the layer and can be fixed by adding the CSS property 'cursor-events: none' to the popup.  That should stop the flickering and shouldn't interfere with the layers.